# OData and case sensitivity

Tags: asp.net, .net, odata

I've been messing with the OData and realized that URIs are case sensitive. .../Northwind.svc/Products != .../Northwind.svc/products
Is this done on purpose? is there a way to make it case insensitive?

Answer (score 4):

The recommended solution is to either use the supported OData functions `toupper` or `tolower` to work out the case sensitivity issues (when using a `filter$` command) and get the full result set.

I wrote a brief post explaining this a bit further in detail:
[Dealing With Case Sensitivity in OData](http://allen-conway-dotnet.blogspot.com/2013/05/dealing-with-case-sensitivity-in-odata.html)

Comment: I like your write-up, but `toupper` and `tolower` are only available when you're inside a `$filter` expression. In the original question here, the poster was trying to have case-insensitivity on an entity set in the path portion of the URI.

Comment: @JenS - you are right. I read that too quickly and focused on the title of the question which I ran into the issue today. If it's out of line I can certainly delete it.

Comment: No, I think your post adds value (especially given the current title of the question and what others might be searching for). Just want people to be aware it won't solve the issue of case sensitivity of an entity set.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example:

```
/people?$filter=tolower(Name) eq tolower('jAmes') -
```

This would return you all people with name is 'James' (case insensitive, could be 'JAMES', 'james', 'JamES', etc.
Hope this will help

Comment: long time later nitpick: that wouldn't work, since "john" is nowhere near "james" no matter what cases you pick.  My brother "James" and I are definitely not equivalent :D