# Aurelia-slickgrid case insensitive search odata api

Tags: aurelia, slickgrid, aurelia-slickgrid

I am trying to search Names using column search bar in aurelia slickgrid. This works with backend odata api

```
d/Customers?$count=true&$filter=(IsActive%20eq%20true%20and%20contains(Name,%20%27So%27))
```

But when i try to search small cased letters, it does not respond anything.

```
d/Customers?$count=true&$filter=(IsActive%20eq%20true%20and%20contains(Name,%20%27so%27))
```

Is there something i can do from aurelia-slickgrid to fix this? I also tried using this but i think backend complains that it does not have substring in filter.

```
$filter=(substringof('fol', Name))
```

My column looks like

```
this.customerColumnDefinition =
        [
            { 
                id: "Name", name: "Name", field: "Name", sortable: true, type: FieldType.string, filterable: true, minWidth: 100,
                onCellClick: (e: Event, args: OnEventArgs): void => { this.router.navigateToRoute("customer", { businessUnitId: args.dataContext.Id }); }
            },
```

Comment: even though I added that OData service, I haven't used it in a few years but I found this other [SO - OData and case sensitivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170575/odata-and-case-sensitivity) so maybe the OData is not case insensitive I don't know but there's 2 services that are located at Slickgrid-Universal [OData](https://github.com/ghiscoding/slickgrid-universal/tree/master/packages/odata/src/services), the OData service does only 1 thing which is to build the OData query with/without filters & sort

Comment: Yes, i read everything. I have the similar solution..`$filter=(IsActive%20eq%20true%20and%20contains(tolower(Name),%20tolower(%27So%27)))` But I didn't wanted to surgically touch the query this way.

Comment: indeed probably better to add code directly in the OData Service to avoid query manipulation. We could add the OData `tolower` as pointed out by that other SO and I can ask another big user of OData to verify the implementation (he's the user who added `select`, `expand` options to OData). Change could be done in this [code](https://github.com/ghiscoding/slickgrid-universal/blob/master/packages/odata/src/services/grid-odata.service.ts#L431-L436) and we could maybe add this under a new flag `caseInsensitive` that would be disabled by default to keep query simple, would you like to create PR?

Comment: let's give it a try then https://github.com/ghiscoding/slickgrid-universal/pull/761 . You can suggest me a bit where else i shall make some changes. I will try it.

Comment: Is it possible to get some callback everytime i type in filter area in my column ? Then i can just take care of casing in callback itself.

Comment: you can get that via the [Grid State](https://github.com/ghiscoding/aurelia-slickgrid/wiki/Grid-State-&-Preset)